# Turing machine without return equivalent to Finite Automaton, PushDown Automaton or Turing Machine?

Tags: turing-machines, pushdown-automata

I have seen that a *Turing machine without return* is a Turing machine $M$ which at each stage of its calculation systematically moves its read / write head to the right.The aim of the exercise is to understand the computing power of Turing machines without return. If a language $L$ is recognise by a Turing machine without return, can we say that $L$ is also equivalent in recognising by a finite automaton, a pushdown automaton or by a Turing Machine? I would tend to say that the $L$ language can be recognized by a Turing machine with no return if and only if $L$ can be recognized by a pushdown automaton because the stack can simulate the movement to the right on tape of the Turing Machine.

Comment: Please don't delete your question after receiving a question.  Part of our mission is to build up an archive of high-quality questions and answers, that will be useful to others as well.

Answer (score 1):

Informally, a pushdown automaton has a way to store and use an infinite amount of memory (the stack). In a Turing machine, the only way to store an infinite amount of memory is to write it on the tape. But in a Turing machine without return, you cannot go back to the cells that you have already written, so that memory can never be used.

That means that a Turing machine without return cannot be "as powerful" as a pushdown automaton. The solution is a finite automaton.

If you want a more formal proof, you can start with the formal definition of a Turing machine without return, note that you can dismiss what you write on the tape (because you can't go back), and construct a finite automaton that recognize the same language as the Turing machine.

Comment: I understand, Thanks! :D